# Get total in observer sales_order_place_before

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, magento-1, event-observer, sales-order

I try to get the total value (price of his order) of the customer in the `sales_order_place_before` event.

How can I read the total value?

This is a part of my observer, it is getting called, I only need to find out how I can read the total value:

```
public function changeCustomerGroup(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    Mage::Log('observer called', 7, 'autochange_customer_group.log', true);


    Mage::Log(var_dump($observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getTotalDue()), 7, 'autochange_customer_group.log', true);
```

But my attempt with `var_dump($observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getTotalDue()` returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it has to be `$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getBaseTotalDue()`